# Get Nearest Value Within the Range - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

With this table, I need to get the DATE value depending on a given (+/-) running total.

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------+
| ID |    DATE    | AMOUNT  | RUNNING TOTAL |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+
| 20 | 2020-04-24 | 2941.18 | 2,941.18       |
| 21 | 2020-05-01 | 2941.18 | 5,882.36       |
| 22 | 2020-05-08 | 2941.18 | 8,823.54       |
| 23 | 2020-05-15 | 2941.18 | 11,764.72      |
| 24 | 2020-05-22 | 2941.18 | 14,705.90      |
| 25 | 2020-05-29 | 2941.18 | 17,647.08      |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+
```

It is easy if the given value of Running Total is exactly the same on what are display in the table. If the given running total is **5, 882.36**, the result is **2020-05-01**; if the given running total is **14, 75.90**, the result is **2020-05-22**; and so on.

However, the given number is not exactly as what is stored in table. For example,

The given Running Total is  **8, 600**, the result should be **2020-05-08** ; 
for **14, 000**, the result should be **2020-05-22**.

I tried this query

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATE FROM Table ORDER BY abs([RunningTotal] - '14000')
```

It almost works fine but if the given Running Total is **14,706** or let say **15,000**, it results to **2020-05-22** instead of **2020-05-29**. The needed result is **2020-05-29** because it's within the running total of record ID # 25.

Comment: I don't understand your case : 8, 600, the result should be 2020-05-08 ; 14, 000,? why? It should not be the nearest bigger? in this case : 2020-05-15

Comment: First of all, remove quotes from 14000.

Comment: Just filter to make sure the difference is not negative. `where running total - 14000 >= 0`. And then you won't need absolute value either. In fact you can sort by just running total.

Comment: If you need the nearest bigger, there's also no point in using `ABS()` and the difference. Just take the top 1 order by total where it's bigger than running total.

Comment: Agreed. `where running total >= 14000` is the same thing.

Comment: @shawnt00 , i already tried using where runningtotal >= 14000.. It will just always return the date value of the table's last row. (For example, the table has date up to December 1, 2020). It will not result to May 22, 2020.

Comment: It isn't particularly clear what your requirement is. You used the phrase "within the running total" but we don't know what that means. Also a mention of "+/-" is nowhere explained.

Comment: Kindly disregard the "(+/-)".. I only mean that the given number to be used in filter is not always exactly as the same on what is listed under tge RunningTotal column (it can be lesser or greater) ...

Comment: Here is the other example on how should it work, if the given number is 5882.36, the result is 2020-05-01. If the given value is 5300.50, the result should 2020-05-01. If the given value is 3500, the result should be 2020-05-01 (not 2020-04-24 because 3500 is greate than 2941.18). If the given value is 2940, the result should be 2020-04-24.. If the given value is 5883, the result should be, 2020-05-08 (not 2020-05-01 because 5883 is greater than 5882.36. It should  work like a "look-up" .

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering and `order by`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t 
where running_total >= @running_total
order by running_total desc
```